# Make depends duplicate rules

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that uses
CC+= -MMD -MP

If I'm using this to generate dependency files and two files generate

headers/all.hh:

This will occur whenever any two files include the same header. They will generate the same rule.

My question is will both rules be executed when the header is changed?

Comment: A generated dependency file usually contains dependencies for a single target (or a small set of related targets) so it's not surprising that multiple dependency files contain certain similar dependencies.  Regarding which rules are executed , you need to show the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not complete rules, because they don't have recipes.  Instead they are simply statements of prerequisites.  You can have as many different statements of prerequisites as you want for the same target, but you can only define one recipe for a given target otherwise make will complain.

So, this:

```
foo: bar biz baz boz band blah
        @do something
```

is exactly identical to this:

```
foo:
        @do something
foo: bar
foo: biz
foo: baz
foo: boz
foo: band
foo: blah
```

which is exactly identical to this:

```
foo: bar biz baz
foo: boz
foo: band blah
foo:
        @do something
```

etc. etc. etc.